# jQuery Daterangepicker trigger click to select the start date

Tags: jquery, daterangepicker

I need a help for jQuery daterangepicker. I am trying to trigger a click and select the startDate while call the daterangepicker. and after that whille I will manually click on the future date it will be treated as enddate and set the  daterange for the daterangepicker. But I am unable to do that.

HTML-

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test datepicker</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="from">
    <div class="panel">
        <p>From Date</p>
        <input type="textbox" name="from" id="from">
    </div>
    <div class="panel">
        <p>To Date</p>
        <input type="textbox" name="to" id="to">
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

JS code is -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var toval = '';
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#from').daterangepicker({
        "showDropdowns": true,
        "singleDatePicker": true
    });

    $("#from").change(function(){
        $('#from').css('color','#000');
        var from =  $("#from").val();
        if(toval=='') {
            $('#to').daterangepicker({
                "showDropdowns": true,
                "autoApply": true,
                "startDate": from,
                "endDate": from
            });
        } else {
            $('#to').daterangepicker({
                "showDropdowns": true,
                "autoApply": true,
                "startDate": from,
                "endDate": from+" - "+toval
            });
        }
        $('#to').css('color','#fff');
        $(".right").hide();
    });

    $("#to").change(function(){
        toval = $("#to").val();
        toval = toval.split(" - ");
        var frm = toval[0];
        toval = toval[1];
        $('#to').val(toval);
        $('#from').val(frm);
        $('#to').css('color','#000');
    });

    if(toval=='') {
        var from =  $("#from").val();
        $('#to').daterangepicker({
            "showDropdowns": true,
            "autoApply": true,
            "startDate": from,
            "endDate": from
        });
    } else {
        $('#to').daterangepicker({
            "showDropdowns": true,
            "autoApply": true,
            "startDate": from,
            "endDate": from+" - "+toval
        });
    }
    $('#to').css('color','#fff');
    $('#from').css('color','#fff');
    $(".right").hide();
});
</script>
```

Please help me on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably start by adding a reference to JQuery at the top of your script includes, because it works just like you say with that:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: He really added JQuery in top :))

Comment: Unlike all the other ones that is a local resource, perhaps it's obsolete.

Comment: @JanAndersen the jQuery library already added. Thats why the datepicker is showing , otherwise the datepicker will not show.

Comment: I copied and tested your code. The only thing I couldn't copy, of course ,was the JQuery reference you are using, because you've added it as a local reference. Using that one above worked like a charm. Btw, you do know that you have set css to color the start text in the same color as the background (at least that's how it appears to me), thus rendering it invisible from the start and until you've picked anything at all?